# how to create Boolean attribute in XML DTD

Tags: xml, types, boolean, dtd

I've never created a DTD before; I can barely read them in fact.  I want to create an attribute that's either true or false.  This is the best I have so far:

```
<!ATTLIST myElement
    someFlag CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

But CDATA is quite a bit looser than just "true or false".  I see here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Attribute_list_declarations
There's an example that looks like I can enumerate the valid values so something like this should work:

```
<!ATTLIST myElement
    someFlag (true|false)
>
```

But that means I have to say "true|false" each type I need a bool?  Is that right?  Or am I totally confused?  Is there any reasonably complete but approachable reference for this stuff, or do I have to just read the whole XML spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common DTD pattern is to define an entity for Boolean,

```
<!ENTITY % Boolean "(true|false)">
```

and then use it where needed:

```
<!ATTLIST myElement someFlag %Boolean;>
```